# Resolving TypeVar errors in Python for a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, mypy

I've been adding types to my decorator to make mypy happy. I've been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621789/mypy-untyped-decorator-makes-function-my-method-untyped) and have been looking at [pep 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/). I've made a lot of progress, but I'm getting the error message

```
decorators.py:12: error: A function returning TypeVar should receive at least one argument containing the same TypeVar  [type-var]
decorators.py:12: note: Consider using the upper bound "Callable[..., Any]" instead
```

However, when you look at the code. I have used `bound=Callable[..., Any]` I'm not sure how it wants me to proceed.

Script: decorators.py

```
"""Decorator Functions."""

from typing import Any, Callable, List, TypeVar, Union, cast
from pandas import DataFrame, concat

F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])


# Decorator to process DataFrame with ignore columns
def process_without_columns(
    ignore_cols: List[str], final_cols_order: Union[List[str], None] = None
) -> F:
    """
    Decorate to process a DataFrame, removing specified ignore columns, and then joining them back.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ignore_cols: List[str]
        List of column names to ignore during processing.
    final_cols_order: Union[List[str], None]
        List specifying the desired order of columns in the final DataFrame.
        If None, the original DataFrame's column order will be used. Default is None.

    Returns
    -------
        decorator_process: Decorator function that processes the DataFrame.
    """

    def decorator_process(func: F) -> F:
        def inner(self, data_df: DataFrame, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> DataFrame:
            """
            Inner function that performs the actual processing of the DataFrame.

            Parameters
            ----------
                data_df: DataFrame
                    DataFrame to be processed.
                *args
                    args passed into inner function
                **kwargs
                    Kwargs passed into inner function


            Returns
            -------
                DataFrame: Processed DataFrame with the original columns
            """
            ignore_df = data_df[
                ignore_cols
            ]  # Extract the ignore columns as a separate DataFrame
            data_df = data_df.drop(
                columns=ignore_cols
            )  # Remove the ignore columns from the original DataFrame

            # Process the DataFrame (smaller DataFrame without ignore columns)
            processsed_df = func(self, data_df, *args, **kwargs)

            # Join back the processed DataFrame with the ignore columns DataFrame
            processsed_df = concat([processsed_df, ignore_df], axis=1)

            # Reorder DataFrame columns if final_cols_order is specified
            if final_cols_order is not None:
                processsed_df = processsed_df[final_cols_order]

            return processsed_df

        return cast(F, inner)

    return cast(F, decorator_process)
```

Comment: I think the problem is partly that although `F` can be any type which satisfies the bound `Callable[..., Any]` everywhere that you use `F` it has to be the _same_ type i.e. as soon as mypy finds a usage of `F` then all the `F`s have to match that type. So here there are outer functions annotated with `F` but then the `inner` that is returned has a more definite signature.

Comment: I just updated the return for 'inner' and 'decorator_process' to cast them as F and it still returns the same error

Comment: Does [this approach](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=b3460b51be7a882c1485aca640770220) work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm running in python39 and don't have access to some of those imports

Comment: Import from `typing_extensions`, I added a comment regarding that in a snippet. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944041/using-modern-typing-features-on-older-versions-of-python/71990006#71990006).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing decorators in Python is still a bit problematic.

Here is a version which seems to type-check ok:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, List, TypeVar, Union, cast
from pandas import DataFrame, concat

F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def process_without_columns(
    ignore_cols: List[str], final_cols_order: Union[List[str], None] = None
) -> Callable[[F], F]:

    def decorator_process(func: F) -> F:
        def inner(self: Any, data_df: DataFrame, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> DataFrame:
            ignore_df = data_df[
                ignore_cols
            ]  # Extract the ignore columns as a separate DataFrame
            data_df = data_df.drop(
                columns=ignore_cols
            )  # Remove the ignore columns from the original DataFrame

            # Process the DataFrame (smaller DataFrame without ignore columns)
            processsed_df = func(self, data_df, *args, **kwargs)

            # Join back the processed DataFrame with the ignore columns DataFrame
            processsed_df = concat([processsed_df, ignore_df], axis=1)

            # Reorder DataFrame columns if final_cols_order is specified
            if final_cols_order is not None:
                processsed_df = processsed_df[final_cols_order]

            return processsed_df

        return cast(F, inner)

    return decorator_process
```

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=1496165d26c4f924f652613473b950f3&flags=strict

The main issue was that `F` is the wrong return type for the outer `process_without_columns` function... it actually returns a function which takes an `F` and returns and `F` i.e. another layer of nesting.

Needing the `cast` on the `inner` func is a bit unfortunate though.

I also experimented with another version which uses the features of https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Concatenate, List, ParamSpec, Union, cast
from pandas import DataFrame, concat

P = ParamSpec('P')
F = Callable[Concatenate[Any, DataFrame, P], DataFrame]

def process_without_columns(
    ignore_cols: List[str], final_cols_order: Union[List[str], None] = None
) -> Callable[[F[P]], F[P]]:
    def decorator_process(func: F[P]) -> F[P]:
        def inner(self: Any, data_df: DataFrame, /, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> DataFrame:
            ignore_df = data_df[
                ignore_cols
            ]  # Extract the ignore columns as a separate DataFrame
            data_df = data_df.drop(
                columns=ignore_cols
            )  # Remove the ignore columns from the original DataFrame

            # Process the DataFrame (smaller DataFrame without ignore columns)
            processsed_df = func(self, data_df, *args, **kwargs)

            # Join back the processed DataFrame with the ignore columns DataFrame
            processsed_df = concat([processsed_df, ignore_df], axis=1)

            # Reorder DataFrame columns if final_cols_order is specified
            if final_cols_order is not None:
                processsed_df = processsed_df[final_cols_order]

            return processsed_df

        return inner

    return decorator_process
```

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=6c56fd4381d1fc9bb463965c7c32d7de&flags=strict

We use `ParamSpec` to capture the type of the `*args` and `**kwargs` of the decorated `func`.

Then we need `Concatenate` because there are the positional args `self, data_df` in front of the `*args`

We also had to use `/` in the `inner` def to make them positional-only args - will be a problem if your decorated `func` doesn't do the same.

Comment: I used the top solution, bc I'm currently working in python 3,9 and ParamSpec isn't available until python 3,10