# pythonic way to get type hint checking of dynamically imported methods

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-3.9

Python newb who's struggling to get out of his statically typed OOD habits.

I have a CLI that will support the ability to pipe to methods to transform output.  So I can run something like this:

```
my_command | filter name=bob | sort last_name | to_json
```

To do this I want to have a number of methods defined in my transforms module that all take a results object and args and return a results object post transformation.  Then I read whatever the next argument after a pipe is and try to find a method with that name in my transforms module and pass everything to that method if discovered.

Now I can do just that, but I don't get any type checking or safety that way, where as were using type hinting to sanity test everything else we do.  I'm wondering what the most pythonic way would be to try to keep some sort of type checking on whatever transformation I discover in the module?

I could create an abstract class with a single method, but requiring each transformation to be it's own class just to implement that one method with type safety seems excessive. I briefly thought maybe decorators but my quick peak at them says that decorators don't support type hinting until 3.10 and I'm limited to python 3.9.

Is there a clean pythonic way to try to get type checking here?  or should I just pull whatever method I find and trust it will work right?

Comment: "decorators don't support type hinting until 3.10" - what? You mean `ParamSpec`, probably, but it may a) be not necessary in your case and b) just be imported from `typing_extensions` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944041/using-modern-typing-features-on-older-versions-of-python/71990006#71990006)